# How do I start my grails app locally?

Tags: java, spring, unix, grails

My developer set up an application on my local machine which is built on the Grails/Spring framework. I accidentally deleted the Unix exe script he gave me to run it locally in my browser and can no longer access the site. Unfortunately I cannot get in touch with him till after the holidays and I need to access this site to do work ASAP.

The script I have right now is...

```
#!/bin/sh
grails -Dserver.port.https=443 -Dserver.port=80 run-app -https
```

It just returns errors. Can anyone help me figure out how to get this running locally. Here is the unix errors.

```
Last login: Mon Dec 24 08:34:43 on ttys000
/Users/admin/Projects/.... ; exit;
gio-2:~ admin$ /Users/admin/Projects/.... ; exit;
| Configuring classpath
| Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/admin/.grails/.slcache/.index (Permission    denied)
| Error     at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
| Error     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:192)
| Error     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
| Error     at   com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.addToCacheIndex(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:326    )
| Error     at  com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:271)
| Error     at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewriteUsingCache(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:1 41)
| Error     at  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java: 775)
| Error     at com.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.j ava:251)
| Error     at com.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:89)
| Error     at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
| Error     at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
| Error     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.oldFindClass(RootLoader.java:152)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:124)
| Error     at    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:228)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error     at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Error executing script RunApp: /Users/admin/.grails/ivy-cache/resolved-org.grails.internal-grails-2.0.3.xml (Permission denied) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
logout
[Process completed]
```

I tried using sudo it gives this error...

```
/Users/admin/Projects/... 2 ; exit;
gio-2:~ admin$ /Users/admin/Projects/... 2 ; exit;
Password:
| Configuring classpath
| Error /Users/admin does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
| Error The following commands are supported outside of a project:
add-proxy
clear-proxy
create-app
create-plugin
help
list-plugins
package-plugin
plugin-info
remove-proxy
set-proxy
 | Run 'grails help' for a complete list of available scripts.
 logout

 [Process completed]
```

I don't know if this helps but the I have a grails-2.0.3 file in a Users/admin/Tools directory. Again, I didn't set any of this up so I don't really know the in/out of how this is set up. I just need to be able to see it on my local servers via http so I can complete my front end work.

This is the script that worked...

```
#!/bin/sh 
cd /Users/admin/Projects/...
sudo grails -Dserver.port.https=443 -Dserver.port=80 run-app -https
```

Comment: Grails can't wirte in /Users/admin. Try run it as user "admin"

Comment: Hmmm I am not quite sure I know how to accomplish that but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the edit I didn't realize I dropped the 'g'

Comment: How do I actually implement what Fabiano suggested? I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run the app with admin authority, try:

```
sudo grails -Dserver.port.https=443 -Dserver.port=80 run-app -https
```

And the message said:

```
 Error /Users/admin does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
```

So, you are not in the right project directory to run that command.

For example, your project directory is /Users/admin/workspace/myProject, you should `cd` to that path. If your `ls` command show you some contents like:

```
application.properties scripts                test
src                    stacktrace.log         web-app
grails-app             target
lib                    target-eclipse
```

then you can issue the first run-app command.